# How to connect to Oracle using Service Name instead of SID

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, connection-string, service-name

I have a Java application that uses JDBC (via JPA) that was connecting to a development database using hostname, port and Oracle SID, like this:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle.hostserver1.mydomain.ca:1521:XYZ
```

XYZ was the Oracle SID. Now I need to connect to a different Oracle database that does not use a SID, but uses an Oracle "Service Name" instead.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle.hostserver2.mydomain.ca:1522:ABCD
```

ABCD is the Service Name of the other database.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 500, accepted):

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/urls.htm#BEIDHCBA

> ***Thin-style Service Name Syntax***
>
> Thin-style service names are supported only by the JDBC Thin driver. The syntax is:
>
> @//host_name:port_number/service_name
>
> For example:
>
> jdbc:oracle:thin:scott/tiger@//myhost:1521/myservicename

So I would try:

***jdbc:oracle:thin:@//oracle.hostserver2.mydomain.ca:1522/ABCD***

Also, per Robert Greathouse's answer, you can also specify the TNS name in the JDBC URL as below:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS =(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=blah.example.com)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=BLAHSID)(GLOBAL_NAME=BLAHSID.WORLD)(SERVER=DEDICATED)))
```

Comment: Can you incorporate the point about TNSNAMES format per answer from @Robert Greathouse to achieve answer perfection?

Comment: For me it didn't work with the @, I had to use jdbc:oracle:thin://myhost:1521/myservicename, but also I didn't provide user credentials

Comment: I've been trying to figure out how to connect to Oracle using JDBC thin driver on Google App Script and tried a number of syntax without success. `jdbc:oracle:thin:USER/PWD@//my.ip.address:1521/SERVICENAME` or `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//my.ip.address.1521/SERVICENAME` , with username and password as arguments to `jdbc.getConnection()`. Still puzzling.

Answer (score 113):

So there are two easy ways to make this work. The solution posted by Bert F works fine if you don't need to supply any other special Oracle-specific connection properties. The format for that is:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//HOSTNAME:PORT/SERVICENAME
```

However, if you need to supply other Oracle-specific connection properties then you need to use the long TNSNAMES style. I had to do this recently to enable Oracle shared connections (where the server does its own connection pooling). The TNS format is:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description=(address=(host=HOSTNAME)(protocol=tcp)(port=PORT))(connect_data=(service_name=SERVICENAME)(server=SHARED)))
```

If you're familiar with the Oracle TNSNAMES file format, then this should look familiar to you. If not then just Google it for the details.

Comment: Is the service name the name of the schema?

Answer (score 25):

You can also specify the TNS name in the JDBC URL as below

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS =(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=blah.example.com)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=BLAHSID)(GLOBAL_NAME=BLAHSID.WORLD)(SERVER=DEDICATED)))
```

Answer (score 23):

Try this: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle.hostserver2.mydomain.ca:1522/ABCD`

Edit: per comment below this is actualy correct: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//oracle.hostserver2.mydomain.ca:1522/ABCD` (note the `//`)

Here is a [link](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC) to a helpful article

Comment: This didn't work for me, I had to use `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//oracle.hostserver2.mydomain.ca:1522/ABCD`.

Comment: So the IP can be used here instead of `oracle.hostserver2.mydomain.ca`?

Answer (score 10):

This discussion helped me resolve the issue I was struggling with for days. I looked around all over the internet until I found the answered by Jim Tough on May 18 '11 at 15:17. With that answer I was able to connect. Now I want to give back and help others with a complete example. Here goes:

```
import java.sql.*; 

public class MyDBConnect {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

        try { 
            String dbURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=whatEverYourHostNameIs)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=yourServiceName)))";
            String strUserID = "yourUserId";
            String strPassword = "yourPassword";
            Connection myConnection=DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL,strUserID,strPassword);

            Statement sqlStatement = myConnection.createStatement();
            String readRecordSQL = "select * from sa_work_order where WORK_ORDER_NO = '1503090' ";  
            ResultSet myResultSet = sqlStatement.executeQuery(readRecordSQL);
            while (myResultSet.next()) {
                System.out.println("Record values: " + myResultSet.getString("WORK_ORDER_NO"));
            }
            myResultSet.close();
            myConnection.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using eclipse to connect oracle without SID. There are two drivers to select i.e., Oracle thin driver and other is other driver. Select other drivers and enter service name in database column. Now you can connect directly using service name without SID.

Comment: More importantly this allows you to fully specify the connection URL unlike the Thin Driver. Funny thing is, you still have to use the thin driver URL to get it to work (thin style service names only supported by JDBC thin driver). Plenty of examples posted here.

Answer (score 0):

When using `dag` instead of `thin`, the syntax below pointing to service name worked for me.  The `jdbc:thin` solutions above did not work.

```
jdbc:dag:oracle://HOSTNAME:1521;ServiceName=SERVICE_NAME
```

Comment: Please consider adding some more information to your answer describing a little more on what worked/did not work - what did you observe or know about why this works?

Comment: Worth noting is  - you are using a specific driver. Attempting to use the Oracle's thin driver returns: No suitable driver found for jdbc:dag:oracle://

Answer (score -2):

This should be working: `jdbc:oracle:thin//hostname:Port/ServiceName=SERVICE_NAME`

Comment: Error: "Invalid Oracle URL specified", 11g/ojdbc7 combination.