# Java ORA-01034: ORACLE not available

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, eclipselink

My problem is in Exception Block I have shown,I can connect using GUI(PL/SQL developer) but my Eclipsedlink is getting exception while getting connection using Web Application. Please help me.
Thanks in Advance.

I am using ojdbc14.jar, I am getting connection using Normal java(core), but with Eclipse link alone this problem exists.

Tesing.java :

```
        String URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@IP:1521:devt2x";
        String USER = "username";
        String PASS = "password";
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
        if(conn != null)
            System.out.println("connects");
        else
            System.out.println("not connects");

ouput :
```

**`connects`**

tnsnames.ora

```
CHENNAIDB.WORLD =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = IP)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = IP)(PORT = 1526))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = devt2x)
    )
  )
```

Persistence.xml

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = IP)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME =  devt2x)(SERVER = DEDICATED)))" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="username" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password" />
```

Exception I am getting : No problem in mapping

```
[EL Finer]: 2012-11-20 11:39:39.021--ServerSession(2693887)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--DriverManager connect failed, trying direct connect.
[EL Finer]: 2012-11-20 11:39:39.021--ServerSession(2693887)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27123: unable to attach to shared memory segment
Linux Error: 13: Permission denied
```

Comment: It is a permission issue, you can have a look at [this](http://sabdarsyed.blogspot.com/2009/01/ora-27123-unable-to-attach-to-shared.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, No connection pooling just I am testing, That's all.

Comment: Go through [this](http://arjudba.blogspot.com/2008/05/ora-27123-unable-to-attach-to-shared.html) as well

Comment: I checked that but why I can get connection with JDBC but I couldn't with Eclipselink(JPA).

Comment: Try connecting using sqlplus and see.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19801/discussion-between-sunleo-and-polppan)

Comment: Please check the following link [here](http://techtopicsbyme.blogspot.com/2016/07/ora-01034-oracle-not-available.html)

Comment: Please check the URL > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832056/java-jdbc-how-to-connect-to-oracle-using-service-name-instead-of-sid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely this is a permission issue which needs to be resolved by providing permission to ORACLE_HOME to user say oracle (or whatever os user created for installation of Oracle database).

More details can be found [here](http://arjudba.blogspot.com/2008/05/ora-27123-unable-to-attach-to-shared.html)

Comment: Link is broken. Please update answer or provide new url.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Database bridge or your Database cant start up.