# Could not create ConnectionPool Oracle in Glassfish

Tags: oracle, glassfish, pool

I'm trying create in Glassfish JDBC Connection Pool.

I'm use this following settings

```
Resource type: javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource
Datasource Classname: oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource
url:jdbc:oracle:thin:ip_address:1521
```

when i tryed ping, i get next error:

```
[2013-11-01T09:41:46.674+0400] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [test.connection.pool.failed] [javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service] [tid: _ThreadID=124 _ThreadName=admin-listener(7)] [timeMillis: 1383284506674] [levelValue: 900] [[
  RAR8054: Exception while creating an unpooled [test] connection for pool [ OraclePool ], Connection could not be allocated because: I / O error:: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection]]


Timestamp   Nov 1, 2013 09:28:39.892
Log Level  WARNING
Logger javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service
Name-Value Pairs  {levelValue=900, timeMillis=1383283719892}
Record Number  759
Message ID  test.connection.pool.failed
Complete Message   RAR8054: Exception while creating an unpooled [test] connection for pool [ ConnectionOraclePool ], Connection could not be allocated because: Ошибка ввода/вывода: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

Upd. for testing i'm tried turn off firewall - there are no changes. JDBC Resource from JDBC Connection Pool i'm  created. Surfing similar order has not helped

OJBC Driver in: ../glassfish\domains\domain1\lib

Comment: can you create a thin jdbc connection using the same url from the same location?

Comment: Answer of my question there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4832116/1755546.

Comment: Normally I would expect a service_name or Oracle_sid to be part of the URL. I don't see it.