# Is it possible to define Oracle connection containing SID as a single parameter?

Tags: java, connection-string

I have written a class for connecting to Oracle database using `ServiceName` in the below format.

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:username/password@//host:port/serviceName);
```

Is it possible to do the same using `SID`?
What I want to achieve is to convert the below 3 connection parameters in the `getConnection` method to a single parameter like the above code.

```
connection = DriverManger.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:SID", username, password);
```

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Have you tested with `DriverManager#getConnection(String url, String user, String password)`! is there any exception ?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832056/java-jdbc-how-to-connect-to-oracle-using-service-name-instead-of-sid

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder, Yes I have tested it. No exceptions.