# Error connecting to Oracle database using JDBC

Tags: java, database, oracle, jdbc

I have an Oracle database that has been created within the connection shown in the [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hahCp.png) below.

[image]

I have created the same database on another connection that runs on the localhost and connected it using JDBC and the outcome of this is perfect. The code I am currently using to connect this is :-

```
@SuppressWarnings("finally")
public Connection connectToDatabase() {
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        String URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@etna.doc.stu.mmu.ac.uk:1521/docm";
        String USER = "C12001165";
        String PASS = "C12001165";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
    } catch (SQLException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        return conn;
    }
}
```

Am i connecting it the right way or is the an alternate method that could be used to complete this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT - Error Message**

Apologise, forgot to include the error message. It is shown below.

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:489)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:553)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:254)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:528)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at StaffServer.connectToDatabase(StaffServer.java:434)
at StaffServer.doGet(StaffServer.java:312)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:439)
at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:454)
at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:693)
at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:251)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1140)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:340)
... 30 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:149)
at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:133)
at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:405)
... 35 more
Apr 23, 2015 12:31:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [StaffServer] in context with path [/Staff_Servers] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at StaffServer.doGet(StaffServer.java:317)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: Please remove the `Class.forName` line, that isn't needed anymore with recent JDBC drivers, they register themselves.

Comment: Removed the Class.forName line and it still does not work. Thank you for the suggestion though, i will bare it in mind next time i use the JDBC.

Comment: Depending on JDBC version, you might need to add `//` after `@`. I mean, on newer versions, your URL should be : `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//etna.doc.stu.mmu.ac.uk:1521/docm`. Look first answer in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832056/java-jdbc-how-to-connect-to-oracle-using-service-name-instead-of-sid)

Comment: And also you can have experiment with connection in SQLDeveloper by choosing Advanced connection type

Comment: Still no luck with the changes, i've checked everything that was within the post sent by Albert as well as within the duplicate question that has been brought to my attention and still no joy.