# JAVA- JDBC- ORACLE Connection issues

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Using standard JDBC code for JAVA-ORACLE connection however not working.

This may be asked earlier but i am not able to debug it myself so asking here.
Request for help.

Code:

```
import java.sql.*;
class OracleCon {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        // step1 load the driver class
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

        // step2 create the connection object
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "system",
                "nikhil.nik");

        /*
         * Hostname: Host system for the Oracle database. For your Express
         * Edition database, the hostname is localhost. Port: Listener port.
         * The default is 1521. SID: Database name. The default for Express
         * Edition is xe.
         */

        // step3 create the statement object
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

        // step4 execute query
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT TEST_NAME FROM TEST1");
        // System.out.println(rs);

        while (rs.next())
            System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) + "  " + rs.getString(2) + "  "
                    + rs.getString(3));

        // step5 close the connection object
        con.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```

}

Stacktrace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation 
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112) 
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146) 
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:208) 
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.CharCommonAccessor.getInt(CharCommonAccessor.java:132) 
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getInt(OracleResultSetImpl.java:521) 
  at dbPrograms.OracleCon.main(OracleCon.java:31)
```

Comment: You select a single column but access three columns in the result.

Comment: Show the full stacktrace with `e.printStackTrace();`. Your way loses all the important information in the exception.

Comment: posting the stacktrace:

java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:208)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.CharCommonAccessor.getInt(CharCommonAccessor.java:132)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getInt(OracleResultSetImpl.java:521)
 at dbPrograms.OracleCon.main(OracleCon.java:31)

Comment: @NikhilKumar then the column `TEST_NAME` is not a `int`

Comment: Thanks everyone, the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You selected column `TEST_NAME` and extracted its values as `int`. This operation fails because Oracle cannot convert the values accordingly. Use the `ResultSet` method suitable for the column type.

Also you select one column and access three columns in the `ResultSet` so you might want to adjust the select command.

Comment: Hi Wero,
one more doubt. Here in the code I am not selecting my 'Emloyee' database. So, how to select the database. Suppose if I have same table in two databases then how to retrieve the values.'xe' is the SID.

Comment: @NikhilKumar not an expert in oracle. Guess you specify the database in the connection url as you already did. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832056/java-jdbc-how-to-connect-to-oracle-using-service-name-instead-of-sid might help.