# Unable to get oracle database connection

Tags: jdbc, oracle11g, websphere-8, ojdbc, ibm-jdk

1.JAVA_HOME is set to IBM JAVA SDK.
2.Unable to get oracle database connection. Where as tried running the same on machine having Oracle java set as JAVA_HOME
3.Placed ojdbc14.jar under AppServer/lib.

```
   try {

  connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
      "jdbc:oracle:thin:@[server-ip]:[server-port]/[dbname]", "[uname]", "[pass]");

} catch (SQLException e) {

  System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
  e.printStackTrace();
  return;

}

if (connection != null) {
  System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
} else {
  System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
}
```

Is there any setting i need to do.Below is the error

> Oracle JDBC Driver Registered! Connection Failed! Check output console
> java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could
> not establish the connection
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:517)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.(PhysicalConnection.java:557)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.(T4CConnection.java:233)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:29)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:556)
> at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:583)
> at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:227)
> at OracleJDBCExample.main(OracleJDBCExample.java:29) Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not
> establish the connection
> at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:389)
> at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:431)
> at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:882)
> at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:267)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1625)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:365)
> ... 7 more Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
> at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
> at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:370)
> at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:231)
> at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:213)
> at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:404)
> at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:643)
> at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:147)
> at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:130)
> at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:367)

Thanks,
Kusuma

Comment: Your question is missing a lot of essential information: show us a [MCVE] (hint: where's your source code? )

Comment: Ran the example from here https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/connect-to-oracle-db-via-jdbc-driver-java/ @FrankSchmitt

Comment: This is not only with Oracle i am having connection issue with Mysql as well. This happens only with IBM java SDK @FrankSchmitt

Comment: Have you actually read how to post a [MCVE] ? Linking external HOWTO's articles / doesn't help - do you really expect everybody on SO will read an external tutorial just to answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple of things to check:

- can you connect to port [server-port] on [server-ip] ? (try telnet, netcat or something similar)
- does the listener accept connections? i.e. does sqlplus username/pw@[server-ip]:[server-port]/[dbname] work?
- is the SID correct (dbname) ?
- have you tried connecting with the service name instead of the SID:
  `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//<server-ip>:<server-port>/<dbname>` ?

see also
[Java JDBC - How to connect to Oracle using Service Name instead of SID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832056/java-jdbc-how-to-connect-to-oracle-using-service-name-instead-of-sid)