# swingbench datagenerator connect string

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, jdbc, oracle12c

I need to use [swingbench](http://dominicgiles.com/swingbench.html) to quantify performance of a given host. However since I am pretty new to Databases as such cannot get the [datagenerator](http://dominicgiles.com/datagenerator.html) program to connect to an Oracle DB instance that has been "opened" on the host.

After installing Oracle 12c on the host (and creating a DB along with it), I am starting the DB as such

For the very first time, I was facing issues starting the DB since the initialization file was not present. So I had to create a 'pfile' from an existing 'spfile' which I found present at $ORACLE_HOME

```
SQL> CREATE PFILE = full path to init.ora FROM SPFILE = full path to existing spfile.ora;
```

After that I start the DB which '*mounts*' and '*opens*' the database.

```
SQL> startup
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 2421825536 bytes
Fixed Size                  2291232 bytes
Variable Size             654313952 bytes
Database Buffers         1744830464 bytes
Redo Buffers               20389888 bytes
Database mounted.
Database opened.
```

The relevant details from my DB are:

```
SQL> SELECT sys_context('USERENV', 'SID') FROM DUAL;

SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SID')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
355

SQL>
SQL> select sys_context('userenv','instance_name') from dual;

SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','INSTANCE_NAME')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
db1

SQL> select sys_context('userenv', 'server_host') from dual;

SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SERVER_HOST')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
oracle_12c
```

My hostname is:

```
oracle_12c.localdomain
```

Now when I try to test the connection from the datagenerator to this database (P.S. from the same host on which the DB is installed), I always get an error. I've tried using both the *service-name* (or is it called the *instance name*??) as well as the SID methods of connection as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832056/java-jdbc-how-to-connect-to-oracle-using-service-name-instead-of-sid). SO on trying using the 'thin style service name syntax' my connect string is:

```
//oracle_12c.localdomain:1521/db1
```

My error is an IO error saying connection couldn't be established without giving out much.

I've tried the 'thin style SID syntax' like so:

```
//oracle_12c.localdomain:1521:355
```

which gives me a similar error without telling much.

The exact error is "Can't connect using parameters supplied : IO Error : Network adapter couldn't establish the connection"

With these details could anyone help me craft a proper connect string to use with datagenerator? Also is there a file on which I can `tail -f` on the host that will point me where exactly it is failing?

ALso I presume that the `listener` does NOT come into the picture for locally originating requests?? Is that true? So does it mean that `listerner.ora` need not be configured for such requests?

EDIT: My Lister configuration file is:

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = oracle_12C.localdomain)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

SID_LIST_LISTENER=
  (SID_LIST=
       (SID_DESC=
         (GLOBAL_DBNAME=db1)
         (SID_NAME=db1)
         (ORACLE_HOME=/oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1)
       )
  )
```

So now after updating this file I start my listener like so:

```
[oracle@oracle_12c db_1]$ lsnrctl start

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production on 06-APR-2017 04:31:38

Copyright (c) 1991, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting /oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1/bin/tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production
System parameter file is /oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Log messages written to /oracle/diag/tnslsnr/oracle_12c/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=oracle_12c.localdomain)(PORT=1521)))

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                06-APR-2017 04:31:39
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 0 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /oracle/diag/tnslsnr/oracle_12c/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=oracle_12c.localdomain)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "db1" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "db1", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Now at least it looks like my request from swingbench is indeed hitting at my DB because now I get a different error:
`ORA-01017: invalid username/password, logon denied`

So now I change the case from `SYS` to `sys` for user to which I get the following error:
`ORA-28009: Connection as SYS should be as SYSDBA or SYSOPER`

I even tried setting the case to insensitive:

```
SQL> ALTER SYSTEM SET SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON = FALSE;
System altered.
```

but to no avail. 
Keen to hear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must configure a tcp listener for the JDBC thin driver - that's used by swingbench - to connect to your database.

In listener.ora you will need something like this:

```
LISTENER = (ADDRESS_LIST= 
 (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=yourhostname)(PORT=yourport))
)
```

And then the listener has to be started using the lsnctrl command line. I assume you have already created a service which will register with the listener automatically. Then and only then will you be able to connect swingbench.

You can then use the long format connections string:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=yourhostname)(PORT=yourport))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=yourervice)))
```

which can also be tested with sqlplus:

```
sqlplus 'scott/tiger@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=yourhostname)(PORT=yourport))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=yourervice)))'
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip and I did try that and it looks I've trudged a bit forward but still not connecting. I've updated my details above

Comment: You should login using a regular user. Connecting as sysdba requires some extra steps.

Comment: Yes was able to connect to the DB after creating a new user. Thanks

Comment: Your post did help me to look in the right direction though I still had to fiddle a bit..
nevertheless thanks for the time Jean!!