# How can I use RapidMiner 5 to connect to an Oracle 12.2 database?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, rapidminer

I'm trying to connect to an Oracle 12.2 database using RapidMiner 5.3.15 (the last free, purely open-source version). I'm using ojdbc8.jar as my driver and Java 8 is installed on my PC. When I test the connection I get the following error:

*Io exception: Invalid connection string format, a valid format is: "host:port:sid"*

This is strange, because I don't receive this error connecting with other software using the service_name rather than SID. The URL that normally works is this:

jdbc:oracle:thin:[host]:1521/[service_name]

Below are the driver details from the jdbc_properties.xml file in my user/.RapidMiner5 folder. Any idea on what could be causing the error?

```
<driver urlprefix="jdbc:oracle:thin:@" name="Oracle12.2" drivers="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" driver_jar="C:\Program Files (x86)\Rapid-I\RapidMiner5\lib\jdbc\ojdbc8.jar" defaultport="1521" dbnameseparator="/"/>
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions/advice-

Tim

Comment: You might need to make the prefix `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//`, or change the `dbnameseparator` to `:`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832056/java-jdbc-how-to-connect-to-oracle-using-service-name-instead-of-sid

Comment: Thanks Mark. When I try this format:
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//[host]:1521/[service_name]

I receive this error:
ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol

Any idea on what this means?

Thanks again

Comment: Try using a long form of the connection URL. 
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(HOST=myhost)(PORT=1521)(PROTOCOL=tcp))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=myorcldbservicename))).  Refer to DataSourceSample.java on Github(https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-examples/blob/master/java/jdbc/ConnectionManagementSamples/DataSourceSample.java)

Answer (score 0):

you need to make url link `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//oracle.hostserver2.mydomain.ca:1522/ABCD`, so you have to use `dbnameseparator=":"` and `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//Host name or IP address`.

https://docs.rapidminer.com/server/administration/creating-connections/creating-db-conns.html

Comment: Thanks Mayank, but using the : for the dbnameseparator throws an error saying the format is not correct. This error doesn't occur if I use / instead.

Comment: I still have the ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol error