# Java::JavaSql::SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error

Tags: java, oracle, elasticsearch, jdbc, logstash

Am executing logstash JDBC config file, while executing the file am getting the below error

`Error: Java::JavaSql::SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
The Connection descriptor used by the client was:
localhost:1521:xe`

Please find my logstash config file :

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "D:\1SearchEngine\data\ojdbc14.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"
    jdbc_user => "ub"
    jdbc_password => "1234567"
    statement => "select * from documents"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "documents"
  }
}
```

But am able to connect database via SQLDeveloper without any issues.

Comment: Try giving SID in Caps: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE

Comment: When you connect from SQLDeveloper you pass `xe` as sid or service name?

Comment: @Ivan i will pass `xe`

Comment: You pass it as `SID` or `Service name`? SQL developer has the following fields for connection: host, port, SID, Service name

Comment: you might want to try jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost/xe as your connect string, that would be using xe as a service name instead of a sid, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832056/java-jdbc-how-to-connect-to-oracle-using-service-name-instead-of-sid

Comment: I hope you are aware that ojdbc14.jar means that it is for Java 1.4 and that the version is probably +/- 15 years old. You should really be using a more recent driver.

Answer (score 0):

In sqldev, you can get the exact jdbc url being used.  Is `show jdbc` in the worksheet ( or in sqlcl ). You can ensure you are connecting the same way in your logstash setup.

Here's an example. See the `Driver URL` line.

Also please update that driver. ojdbc8.jar is current and downloadable from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/jdbc/downloads/index.html

```
SQL> show jdbc
-- Database Info --
Database Product Name: Oracle
Database Product Version: Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
Database Major Version: 12
Database Minor Version: 1
-- Driver Info --
Driver Name: Oracle JDBC driver
Driver Version: 12.2.0.1.0
Driver Major Version: 12
Driver Minor Version: 2
Driver URL: jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:xe
Driver Location: 
resource: oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.class
jar: /Users/klrice/workspace_commons/dbtools-commons/sqlcl/target/dbtools-sqlcl-18.1.0-SNAPSHOT-sqlcl/dbtools-sqlcl-18.1.0-SNAPSHOT/lib/ojdbc8.jar  
JarSize: 4036257  
JarDate: Thu Jan 25 14:31:44 EST 2018  
resourceSize: 2604  
resourceDate: Tue Dec 13 08:39:48 EST 2016

SQL>
```