# Java Connect oracle DataBase TNS

Tags: java, oracle

I want to connect Oracle DB.

My .ora :

```
AUTACSRV120000, AUTACSRV120000.world =
    (DESCRIPTION = 
        (ADDRESS_LIST = 
            (FAILOVER = ON)
            (LOAD_BALANCE = OFF)
            (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = infra-dbaas01.noe.rct.fr)(PORT = 1521))
            (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = infra-dbaas02.pcy.rct.fr)(PORT = 1521))
        )
        (LOAD_BALANCE = YES)
        (CONNECT_DATA = 
            (SERVER = DEDICATED)
            (SERVICE_NAME = AUTAC_fes.dbaas.rct.fr)
        )
```

When i want to connect i use

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@AUTACSRV120000, AUTACSRV120000.world
```

result :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Erreur d'E/S: Inval
id connection string format, a valid format is: "host:port:sid"
```

But if i edit .ora to

```
AUTACSRV120000 =
    (DESCRIPTION = 
        (ADDRESS_LIST = 
            (FAILOVER = ON)
            (LOAD_BALANCE = OFF)
            (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = infra-dbaas01.noe.rct.fr)(PORT = 1521))
            (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = infra-dbaas02.pcy.rct.fr)(PORT = 1521))
        )
        (LOAD_BALANCE = YES)
        (CONNECT_DATA = 
            (SERVER = DEDICATED)
            (SERVICE_NAME = AUTAC_fes.dbaas.rct.fr)
        )
```

and use

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@AUTACSRV120000
```

The connection is OK

I do not have the right to leave the file edit.

Comment: Try using jdbc:oracle:thin:@//ipadress:portnumber/service_name

Comment: Did you try using jdbc:oracle:thin:@AICSRV120000 without editing .ora file?

Comment: Yes i try and result is "Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Erreur d'E/S: could
 not resolve the connect identifier  "AUTACSRV120000""

Answer (score 0):

Possibly two options:
1) use the service name to connect similar to here ([Java JDBC - How to connect to Oracle using Service Name instead of SID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832056/java-jdbc-how-to-connect-to-oracle-using-service-name-instead-of-sid))   but I was able to test this only by using one host. so in your example:
DB URL will be:
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//infra-dbaas01.noe.rct.fr:1522/AUTAC_fes.dbaas.rct.fr

2) we can use the TNS entry as is in the connection description as mentioned here:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/jdbcthin.htm

```
    String connString = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description=(address_list=
   (address=(protocol=tcp)(port=1521)(host=prodHost)))
(connect_data=(INSTANCE_NAME=ORCL)))";
  OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();

ods.setURL(connString);
ods.setUser("scott");
ods.setPassword("tiger");
Connection conn = ods.getConnection();
```

Answer (score 0):

JDBC Thin connection supports only one TNS alias. So, you cannot provide 
"jdbc:oracle:thin:@AUTACSRV120000, AUTACSRV120000.world". You should try with only one TNS alias name.