# How to set useUnicode=yes& characterEncoding=UTF-8 in DBCPConnectionPool for Oracle in NIFI?

Tags: oracle, apache-nifi

I am using DBCPConnectionPool in order to create a connection and extract data from Oracle DB. But data results were extracted with wrong font. I guess it's due to not set UTF-8 in connection string.

I found a example when set DBCPConnectionPool for MySQL with utf-8: 
Database Connection URL is set as below:

> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8.

But I am not sure how does look like for Oracle.
Could you please help me give any solution? Thanks.

Comment: did you see the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6047081

Comment: No. It's not look like what I need :( thx

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-url-format.html

Comment: question seems about mysql database and not about oracle. right?

Comment: No. I am asking about oracle. I can find this case for MySql but cannot find for oracle. So I need a support.

Comment: All db drivers has different properties. For Oracle no such parameters. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.html

Comment: So you know how to set encoding=utf-8 in DBCPConnectionPool for Oracle in NIFI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This page might be helpful](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch6unicode.htm) to understand the intricacies of Unicode support in Oracle. To convert ASCII to UTF-8 in NiFi, use the [`ConvertCharacterSet`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ConvertCharacterSet/index.html) processor.

Comment: Thx :) I solved this issue without any changes in Nifi. Originally results of ExecuteSQL processor in Nifi are default with UTF-8. But due to something is wrong from my internal side, so I opened content in result with wrong font :(