# Getting MySQL error stack trace on Oracle JDBC Connection

Tags: oracle, jdbc, mysql-connector

I am facing very odd error while making Oracle JDBC connection using a connection string. I am giving username as "sys"(which should be sys as sysdba) and ideally, it should come through ojdbc6.jar but in my case, it is coming from mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar which is also included in my project. Please help as I have to keep both the jars in my project.

When I remove the mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar, I get the expected oracle error mentioned below.

```java
private static Connection createConnectionOracle() {
            Connection conn = null;

            try {
                 Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                 conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@ (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.0.151)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)))","sys","sys");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             return conn;
        }
```

**Actual Result:**

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: Malformed database URL, failed to parse the main URL sections.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:108)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:95)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:87)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:71)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:79)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:131)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:231)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at com.dataguise.discoverAgent.util.Test.createConnectionOracle(Test.java:399)
    at com.dataguise.discoverAgent.util.Test.main(Test.java:29)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.UnableToConnectException: Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: Malformed database URL, failed to parse the main URL sections.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:59)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:103)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: Malformed database URL, failed to parse the main URL sections.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:59)
    at com.mysql.cj.conf.ConnectionUrlParser.parseConnectionString(ConnectionUrlParser.java:139)
    at com.mysql.cj.conf.ConnectionUrlParser.<init>(ConnectionUrlParser.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.conf.ConnectionUrlParser.parseConnectionString(ConnectionUrlParser.java:118)
    at com.mysql.cj.conf.ConnectionUrl.getConnectionUrlInstance(ConnectionUrl.java:179)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:201)
    ... 4 more
```

**Expected Result:**

```
ava.sql.SQLException: ORA-28009: connection as SYS should be as SYSDBA or SYSOPER

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:389)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:382)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:600)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:445)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:380)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:760)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:401)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:546)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:236)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at com.dataguise.discoverAgent.util.Test.createConnectionOracle(Test.java:399)
    at com.dataguise.discoverAgent.util.Test.main(Test.java:29)
```

Comment: I see a space in your JDBC connection String, also your connection String looks odd (that looks like tnsnames.ora syntax). Try `jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0.151:1521:orcl`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch You can use the tnsnames.ora syntax with the Oracle JDBC driver

Comment: Have you tried trading these two jars places?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs with MySQL Connector/J 8 version 8.0.11 or earlier (and the never released MySQL Connector/J 6 versions). You need to upgrade to 8.0.12 or higher (current latest version is 8.0.17, see https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/).

From the [Connector/J 8.0.12 release notes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-j/8.0/en/news-8-0-12.html):

> When an application tried to connect to a non-MySQL database through
>   some JDBC driver and Connector/J happened to be on the class path
>   also, Connector/J threw a SQLNonTransientConnectionException, which
>   prevented the application from connecting to its database. With this
>   fix, Connector/J returns null whenever a connection string does not
>   start with jdbc:mysql: or mysqlx:, so connections to non-MySQL
>   databases are not blocked. (Bug #26724154, Bug #87600)

See also https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=87600

As background, normally, JDBC drivers that don't support a specific URL (eg based on the sub-protocol after `jdbc:`), should return `null`, and an exception should only be thrown if a URL is for the driver, but there is a problem with the URL or with creating a connection.

However, even with this bug in the MySQL Connector/J driver, you would still be able to connect to an Oracle database, as `DriverManager` will try each driver until it is able to open a connection. If no drivers were able to connect, it will throw the **first** exception thrown by any driver, or - if all drivers returned `null` - it will throw a *"No suitable driver found"* exeption.

In this case it looks like MySQL was the driver tried before the Oracle driver, and as you expect your Oracle connection to fail as well, it just happens to throw the MySQL exception as that was the first exception.

Long story short, update your MySQL Connector/J.

Comment: It works for me, thank you much for the detailed explanation.