# JDBC - Cant connect to Oracle using Service Name

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, connection-string, service-name

I have been trying to connect to this Oracle database with JDBC **thin** driver with the following syntax:

```
var URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//16.161.286.56:1522/Service_Name"; 
var USER = "user";
var PASS = "password";
var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
```

I keep on having the same response when I execute this:

**We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again. [87a99af]**

Would anyone have an idea of what I am doing wrong ?

---

Also, when I change the IP address to its 'string version':

```
var URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//mydomain.com:1522/Service_Name";
```

Then I get the error response:

> Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password.

Which does not make sense to me as both expressions are supposed to be equivalent ...

Comment: Do you have any stacktraces / sql error codes you can add? Also make sure that the domain can actually be resolved.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832056/java-jdbc-how-to-connect-to-oracle-using-service-name-instead-of-sid?rq=1

Comment: Hi @MarkRotteveel thanks for the answer. I stumbled upon this question before asking mine. I figured that maybe I get a server error because the Oracle server I am trying to connect with may not have Google scripts IP ranges whitelisted..... I will explore that solution today. Still, I do not understand why changing the domain name by its IP address number version gives me a different response

Answer (score 1):

The actual format of Oracle JDBC connection using service name is:

```
@//host_name:port_number/service_name
```

Make sure that is service name is ok.
You can try with TNSNameListener

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description=(address=(host=<HOSTADDRESS>)(protocol=tcp)(port=<PORT>))(connect_data=(service_name=<SERVICENAME>)(server=<SHARED>)))
```

The TNSNameListener file location:

```
<ORACLE_HOME>\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
example: /home/oracle/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
```

Comment: Hi @Sanower Tamjit. I am using exactly the syntax you say in your first line: @//host_name:port_number/service_name

Comment: Also tried your second version with TNSNameListener but it keeps saying that the argument URL passed to .getConnection() is invalid

Comment: What is your service name?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which class is that Jdbc is. Take a look at the [JDBCUrlSample.java](https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-examples/blob/master/java/jdbc/BasicSamples/JDBCUrlSample.java) and [DataSourceSample.java](https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-examples/blob/master/java/jdbc/ConnectionSamples/DataSourceSample.java)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

jdbc:oracle:thin:@//hostname:1521/ServiceName