# Reverse Engineer JDBC Oracle Connection String

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, connection-string, sqoop

Through my research, I wasn't able to find a duplicate of this question (a similar format wasn't include in any of [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832056/java-jdbc-how-to-connect-to-oracle-using-service-name-instead-of-sid)), but please mark it as such if it already exists.

I have the following JDBC connection string to connect to an Oracle database that I am trying to reverse engineer to connect elsewhere, but I don't know which components are server and which are database.

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@word1://word2:port/word3,cn=word4,dc=word5,dc=word6
```

This was used to connect as part of a Sqoop job. The username and password are provided separately, so I don't believe any of these components are username or password. Could someone help me map these words and what their use case is?

Are any of these the database?

Comment: Looks like LDAP syntax: see https://razorsql.com/articles/oracle_ldap_jdbc_connect.html and https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/urls.htm, Believe your database name would be word3 in this example, word 2 would be your LDAP context/OID, cn stands for "Common Name", and dc for "Domain Component".

Comment: Is the <Database Service Name> here the name of the database? Or is the database service something different?

Comment: Oracle's database is certainty not my specialty, but I would presume so (that is, word3 would be the DB name in the example). This thread from Oracle's site seems to indicate such: https://community.oracle.com/thread/1042180

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reverse engineer this URL you start with `@word1`.

According to the Oracle documentation (see reference below), the part of the URL following the `jdbc:oracle:thin:` is the data source.  There are a variety of different data source types, and the syntax of the next first component (including the `@` if present) will determine the type.  The documentation lists the following data source types:

- Oracle Net connection descriptor - `@(...)`
- Thin-style service name - `name@`
- LDAP syntax - `@ldap`
- Bequeath syntax - `oci:path/@`
- TMSNames alias - `@name`

If there was no more context, you just read the documentation to decode the rest of the URL, per the data source type.

But you have revealed that there are `cn` and `dc` parameters in the URL.  That makes it 99.9% likely that this is actually an `@ldap` data source.

The structure of an JDBC URL with an LDAP data source is:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://<host>:<port>/<name>,<ldap context param>...
```

where `<host>` and `<port>` are for an LDAP service, and the ldap context parameters are a list of name=value pairs which should include `cn=OracleContext`.

This tells the JDBC driver to lookup `<name>` in the LDAP server with the given context, and then use the associated information to establish the database connection.  I couldn't find a definitive reference for what `<name>` actually is.  The Oracle documentation just gives an example.

The best I could find is this:

> Database Service Name: The database service name tells the driver what database to connect to. For example, if the database is named "dmart", dmart should be entered as the database service name.

(Source: https://razorsql.com/articles/oracle_ldap_jdbc_connect.html)

The "@ldap" can replaced by "ldaps:", which means LDAP over SSL.

References:

- [Database JDBC Developer's Guide and Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/toc.htm), [Data Sources and URLs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/urls.htm)