# How to add new properties in Weblogic Server 11 JDBC Connection Pool

Tags: weblogic, weblogic11g

I need to include new properties in JDBC ConnectionPool.
On Payara Server 5, I can do it when accessing the menu Domain/Resources/JDBC/JDBC Connection Pools (below my configuration image in Payara Server 5)

[image]

How do I do this on the Weblogic Server 11?

I entered a setting "environment" in field "Parameters".

Would the configuration of additional parameters be like this?

How do I capture the environment information in java? Oracle's documentation is confusing about this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Login to Weblogic Console. Navigate to DataSources. You can create a new one or modify an existing one. Refer to Oracle Documentation. That will help you.

Comment: I left an image of the configuration I made above. Is this configuration correct?

Comment: that's correct when configuring a Thin-style Service Name: duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832056/java-jdbc-how-to-connect-to-oracle-using-service-name-instead-of-sid

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/create-and-deploy-a-java-servlet-using-weblogic-server-wls) for getting the JDBC connection working.