Create apache spark connection to Oracle DB with JDBC
I am trying to create a connection to my company's Oracle test server with Apache spark and scala. Below is the statement I run in the spark-shell. I am using JDK 8 and have installed the appropriate jdbc driver in the jar directory of spark.
Does the syntax for my url or other configurations look incorrect?
Does the error message at the bottom mean anything more useful than "The network adapter could not establish the connection."
scala> val user = <"username">
scala> val password = <"password">

val jdbc = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url","jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =<hostname>)(PORT = 1521))(LOAD_BALANCE = YES)(FAILOVER = YES)(SERVER = DEDICATED)(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = <service name>)(FAILOVER_MODE =(TYPE = SELECT)(METHOD = BASIC)(RETRIES = 180)(DELAY = 5))))").option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").option("query","select * from realmed.office_user_status_type").option("user",username).option("password",password).load()


when the above command executes, it seems like it is trying to connect for a minute or so, and then returns the following error
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: ORA-17820: The network adapter could not establish the connection. (CONNECTION_ID=QDew7TDmTtecLW0yGr39SA==)
https://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-17820/
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.handleLogonNetException(T4CConnection.java:1382)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:975)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:1126)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:104)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:825)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:651)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.connection.BasicConnectionProvider.getConnection(BasicConnectionProvider.scala:49)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.connection.ConnectionProviderBase.create(ConnectionProvider.scala:102)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.JdbcDialect.$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1(JdbcDialects.scala:160)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.JdbcDialect.$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1$adapted(JdbcDialects.scala:156)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.getQueryOutputSchema(JDBCRDD.scala:63)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:58)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation$.getSchema(JDBCRelation.scala:241)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:37)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:346)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:229)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:201)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:172)
  ... 42 elided
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: ORA-17820: The network adapter could not establish the connection. (CONNECTION_ID=QDew7TDmTtecLW0yGr39SA==)
https://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-17820/
  at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:769)
  at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:707)
  at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:938)
  at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:911)
  at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.redirectConnection(NSProtocolNIO.java:525)
  at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.handleConnectPacketResponse(NSProtocolNIO.java:447)
  at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolNIO.java:268)
  at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:331)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connectNetworkSessionProtocol(T4CConnection.java:2947)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:910)
  ... 60 more



Your JDBC URL look's quite weird. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832056/how-to-connect-to-oracle-using-service-name-instead-of-sid for examples.

Your connect string is quite complicated. You do not need FALOVER and LOAD_BALANCE options if you are connecting to standalone (not clustered) database.
Also does this stacktrace contain nested exception with OS error?

@GaëlJ The link you sent gave me an example with the correct syntax. Now apparently I am dealing with user/password error. In the past, I had used this database in Oracle Sql developer with my windows log on credentials. The authentication type for this server is "Kerberos." Im on a different machine now and unsure how login for this database works.

I found a version of the url that works syntactically.This was my main hurdle. However, I have run into invalid username/password, but that is a different issue.
("url","jdbc:oracle:thin:@//<host name>:1521/<service name>").

